# Why isn't drawRect: getting called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I have an `NSView` subclass `foo` which overrides `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [self doStuff];
}
```

I would have expected that whenever I added an instance `bar` of my class as a subview of another view, `bar` would be redrawn. However, when I add `bar` as the `contentView` of the main window in my application, I'm not seeing this to be the case.

I tried adding another override:

```
- (void)viewDidMoveToSuperview
{
    self.needsDisplay = YES;
}
```

...in hopes that when `bar` gained a superview, it would invalidate its display and force a redraw. No such luck (`viewDidMoveToSuperview` is being called, but not `drawRect:`).

I think I may be misunderstanding how `drawRect:` gets called, and I admit that I don't have the best understanding of the drawing event loop in general. I couldn't find a lot of documentation online about this.

So my question is two-fold: 1) What am I doing wrong in regards to getting `drawRect:` called? 2) Is there any relevant online documentation regarding the event loop which draws UI in cocoa?

**EDIT**:

In my UI chain, the instance of `foo` which isn't getting `drawRect:` called on it has two subviews: one which is essentially a subclass of `NSTextView` which sizes to its content, and another which is an `NSScrollView`. By sheer force of luck, I happened to comment out the code which added the `NSScrollView`, and suddenly the instance of `foo` had `drawRect` called on it again.

So somehow my `NSScrollview` is keeping my `foo` from receiving `drawRect:` . From a quick Google search, I found that other people have had reported problems related to drawing and `NSScrollView`. However, most of those posts seemed related to subviews *within* `NSScrollView`, rather than superviews of `NSScrollView`.

So here's my newest question: what about my instance of `NSScrollView` is preventing its parent from receiving `drawRect:`?

Comment: viewDidMoveToSuperview probably doesn't call drawRect:, you should try calling it explicitly with [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding a core part of how Objective-C and Cocoa do properties, `self.needsDisplay = YES` and `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` are the same operation.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen you were already setting needsDisplay and yes, they are the same.

Comment: Just in case - make sure that your view isn't hidden and it has non-zero alpha. Regarding second part of your question - take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/DrawingEnviron/DrawingEnviron.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH202-BBCJDGHJ , "Views and Drawing".

Comment: Thanks for the link, @BorisVerebsky. If nothing else, it confirmed that I'm thinking correctly about the problem in terms of the API I'm using. Also, I checked, and the view isn't hidden.

Comment: You need to show a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show real code.

Comment: If you whole view is hidden behind an opaque view (which can be a child view), the rendering framework can optimize your `drawRect` out of the picture because all it does will be hidden anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to invoke [view display]; instead of needsDiplay ?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, it's a suggestion and should be a comment. You need to wait until you have enough rep to comment.